# Strange characters appeared while writing a message on iOS

Tags: ios, keyboard, emoji, unicode

I was writing a message on AirBnB(iOS app) and quickly pressed the thumbs up(at least I think) and smiley face(U+1F60A) emoji
But instead got this output on the text box:

[image: Screenshot of Character]

Looks like letter 'A' in a black and white square(+reversed variation). Interestingly it wasn't possible to copy these characters, that is it was, but on paste action, nothing was pasted...

I'm really curious what could have caused this, I presume, Unicode letter.
At least I would like to know what exact Unicode characters are these(code)?
Are emojis constructed of 2 Unicode chars so I somehow managed to glitch one emoji inside another and thus made it deconstruct to these individual chars?!

Comment: Have you seen this in any Apple app?

Comment: Nope, first time this happened... I tried provoking it later by maniacally  pressing the emojis, but couldn't reproduce it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emoji with 5 digit numbers are in some circumstances actually composed of 2 special 4 digit characters called surrogates, whose symbols you saw on your screen.  I think having them appear is likely a bug in the app.